# Can we prove that for some $k$ we have the following inequality?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers

I want to prove that that for $k > 3, k \in \mathbb{N}$ there is some $p_k$ which is a prime number and we have that $k < p_k \leq 2k-3$.
Now to show this I want to use Bertrand's postulate, but I am not sure how. I have seen the proof in the book "PROOFS FROM THE BOOK", and the proof is quite involved, however I am thinking that the 5th step in this proof should be helpful (maybe some derivative estimation). Any help is appreciated

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to write just $p$ rather than $p_k$? Because the latter makes it sound like you want specifically the $k$th prime rather than just "some" prime, e.g., for $k = 4$, we have 4 <  7 < 5... oops! 5 is, as you know, the third prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *is* already Bertrand's postulate, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) for a reference with proof:

Bertrand's postulate: For any integer $n>3$, there always exists at least one prime number $p$ with
$$
{\displaystyle n<p<2n-2.}
$$
There are several stronger statements known, e.g., by Dusard,
$$\frac{x}{\ln x}\left(1+\frac{0.992}{\ln x}\right) < \pi(x) < \frac{x}{\ln x}\left(1+\frac{1.2762}{\ln x}\right)$$ 
for all $x\ge 599$. This implies Bertrand's postulate above. For a reference, see here:

[Weak versions of Bertrand's postulate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650804/weak-versions-of-bertrands-postulate?rq=1)

Also on MSE there are some links. This is sometimes called the "stronger form", see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731149/bertrands-postulate-strong-form).

Comment: The proof in the book states it for $p \leq 2n$ so I just have to use it somehow to generalize to the case of $2n-3$

Comment: Exactly, this works as commented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731149/bertrands-postulate-strong-form). But you can also use one of the many stronger results.